# Get site collection lists based on a custom content type using javascript CSOM (JSOM)

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, csom, contenttype

I need to retreive all the lists (list names) that use a specific custom content type in a site collection. I thought this would be easy using the SharePoint API but I cannot really find how.
Off course, the alternative would be to search recursively for all the lists of the webs and check their content types names but I would rather not do this.

Thank you in advance.